# HTTP Request upgrade WebSocket with middleware

Tags: flutter, go, http, websocket

So in my Go/Gin backend i have this routing path /driver/ws, where it goes through 2 middlewares for authentication.

```
driver_confirmed := api.Group("/driver/")
    driver_confirmed.Use(middlewares.CookieAuth())
    driver_confirmed.Use(middlewares.DriverMiddleware)
    driver_confirmed.GET("/ws", func(c *gin.Context) {
        controllers.UpgradeHTTPtoWS(c, rabbitMQChannel, manager)
    })
```

Now in my UpgradeHTTPtoWS func, i am upgrading the HTTP Request to a WebSocket.

So the Idea is that the User getting through all Authentification Middlewares and then establish a WebSocket with the Server.

This is how my frontend looks like, sending a cookie along with some headers for upgrade the HTTP Request to WebSocket.

```
  Future<void> sendHttpRequestWithCookieAndConnectWebSocket() async {
final webSocketKey = generateWebSocketKey(); // Generate a random key
final jsonString = await loadSharedPrefs("cookie");

if (jsonString != null) {
  final url = Uri.https('${globals.serverurl}', '/api/driver/ws');

  final headers = <String, String>{
    'Cookie': '${globals.mipmip}=${Uri.encodeComponent(jsonString)}',
    'Upgrade':
        'websocket', // Include this header to request a WebSocket upgrade
    'Connection': 'Upgrade', // Also include this header
    'Sec-WebSocket-Version': '13',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Key': webSocketKey,
  };

  try {
    final initialResponse = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
    if (initialResponse.statusCode == 101) {
      _webSocketChannel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(url);
      _onlineStatus = true; // Update onlineStatus accordingly
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      _onlineStatus = false; // Update onlineStatus accordingly
      notifyListeners();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error: $e");
  }
}
```

}

The handshake is successful and im getting 101 Response Code from Server. Also in my Server i can see the connection in my "WebSocketManager".

Now this part is giving me a headache, i want send data through that connection. So therefore implementing a WebSocketChannel  `_webSocketChannel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(url);`  but it doesn't work, im getting this error: `WebSocketException: Unsupported URL scheme 'https'` .

I could change my url to ws:// but then i dont come through the middlewares because i cant send a cookie along the ws protocol. So how can i send Data through the established connection? Or What is the best way to authenticate a WebSocket?

Comment: if i use ws:// instead of http:// my first middleware gives me: Cookie not found in request: http: named cookie not present

Comment: You could use a plain `HttpRequest`, then `detachSocket()`, and finally use `WebSocket.fromUpgradedSocket`